# how to add custom listview number of click to action bar in android

Tags: android

Please  help me how to add custom List view's number of clicks to custom action bar (textview) in android?

Here is my `Activity` Class

```
public class DetaisRESTActivity extends Activity {

String valueid,valueid1,valuename;
public int count=0;
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
public int listViewClickCounter=0;

ListAdapterAddItems adapter;

String restaurantmenuname,rastaurantname;

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<ListModel> arraylist;
public static String RASTAURANTNAMEDETAILS = "RestaurantPizzaItemName";
public static String RASTAURANTRUPPEES = "RestaurantPizzaItemPrice";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detais_rest);
 //   getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.titlebar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
   TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.textView123456789);
    Toast.makeText(DetaisRESTActivity.this,listViewClickCounter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mTitleTextView.setText(listViewClickCounter);

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,QuentityActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // get the extra value
    valuename = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenuname");
    valueid = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenunameid");
    valueid1 = intent.getStringExtra("idsrestaurantMenuId5");

    Log.i("valueid",valueid);
    Log.i("valuename",valuename);
    Log.i("valueid1",valueid1);

    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}


// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetaisRESTActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(DetaisRESTActivity.this, "Successs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        //  Log.i("123",value1);
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://firstchoicefood.in/fcfapiphpexpert/phpexpert_restaurantMenuItem.php?r=" + URLEncoder.encode(valuename) + "&resid=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid1) + "&RestaurantCategoryID=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid) + "");



        try {

            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("RestaurantMenItems");
            Log.i("1234",""+jsonarray);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                 ListModel sched = new ListModel();
                sched.setProductName(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemName"));

                sched.setPrice(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemPrice"));

                arraylist.add(sched);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
 final ListView   listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewdetails);

        adapter = new ListAdapterAddItems();

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
            {

                // Get Person "behind" the clicked item
                ListModel p =(ListModel)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                // Log the fields to check if we got the info we want
                Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons: " + p.getCount());
                Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons name: " + p.getProductName());
                Log.i("SomeTag", "Ruppees: " + p.getPrice());

                count++;
                String countString=String.valueOf(count);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Item " + (position + 1),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        countString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });



    }
}

//==========================
class ListAdapterAddItems extends ArrayAdapter<ListModel>
{
    ListAdapterAddItems(){
        super(DetaisRESTActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
        //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartlistitem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arraylist.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView restaurantname = null;
    public TextView ruppees = null;


    ViewHolder(View row) {
        restaurantname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamedetailsrestaurant);
        ruppees = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantcuisinedetalsrestaurant);

    }

    // Notice we have to change our populateFrom() to take an argument of type "Person"
    void populateFrom(ListModel r) {
        restaurantname.setText(r.getProductName());
        ruppees.setText(r.getPrice());

    }


}














    //=============================================================






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detais_rest, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So you want to keep count of each time the user clicks a list view item and then change the action bar title to the number?

Comment: Are you doing this inside an activity or a fragment?

Comment: Inside Activity @AndyJoyce

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first of all declare a instance variable to keep the count of the clicks.

```
public int listViewClickCounter;
```

The on your listview onclick increment the count and call the change action bar method

```
    yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            listViewClickCounter++ 
            changeActionBarTitle();
        }
    });
```

Then implement the change action bar method. You said you have a custom view so you may need to change this a little

```
public void changeActionBarTitle() {

myActionBarCustomTitle.setText("number of clicks =" + String.valueOf(listViewClickCounter));
```

Comment: You increment count but not the listviewcount also you create a string with the value of count but you don't assign it to the action bar text view

Comment: But i completed all the above requirement it also not working

Answer (score 0):

Add a global `int` variable to your class, and in your `ListView` `onItemClickListener` increment this variable `++1` and get a reference to your `TextVie`w and use `TextView.setText(String.ValueOf(that_int_variable));`

**EDIT**

Looking at your code everything looks great, just some arrangements first of all let `mTitleTextView` be global `TextView` object on just in oncreate so you can reference it. You see any variable you declare in a method lives while the method is being called upon. or you can get your actionbar and use the `findViewById()` so your code should look like this

```
String valueid,valueid1,valuename;
public int count=0;
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
public int listViewClickCounter=0;
TextView mTitleTextView; // this is the edit. you add the textview
ListAdapterAddItems adapter;
String restaurantmenuname,rastaurantname;
//then the rest will continue, i skipped all that
```

and instead of setting the text right away in the `TextView` set it when an item has been clicked

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
        {

            // Get Person "behind" the clicked item
            ListModel p =(ListModel)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // Log the fields to check if we got the info we want
            Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons: " + p.getCount());
            Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons name: " + p.getProductName());
            Log.i("SomeTag", "Ruppees: " + p.getPrice());

            count++;
            String countString=String.valueOf(count);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Item " + (position + 1),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();

           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    countString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           mTitleTextView.setText(countString);

        }
    });
```

That is all you need to do also you do not use this `int` variable `listViewClickCounter`

Comment: post your activity Sir,@sundersharma